# Open some files with read-only mode

Tags: read-only-mode

I want some files to be read-only when I open them. Maybe using some kind of header would work?

Parsing the extension would work too but I want to apply to, for example, some ".txt" files so is not very good to apply this rule to all "txt" files.

Comment: In addition to what @Nick says (which is the answer), can you not change the permissions of those files, themselves? If the file is read-only for the file system then the buffer is read-only when you visit it.

Comment: Tanks! I didin't think of that because I just want the readonly so I don't change a file when I open it by mistake. Sometimes I'd like to modify it and Nick's solution is more flexible. But it's not a bad idea!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can add a header to your files, the following should work (it should be the first line in the file):

```
-*- buffer-read-only: t -*-
```

If there is a comment convention (e.g. '# ' for a shell script), you should put it in a comment:

```
# -*- buffer-read-only: t -*-
```

For shell scripts that must have a hash-bang line as the first line, you *can* put the header above on line 2: that's the only exception to the rule AFAIK.

For more details, see [File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) which also describes a method to specify file local variables at the *end* of a file.